# Eclipse Cucumber intelligence failed to show undefined step definition warning

Tags: eclipse, cucumber, cucumber-jvm

Eclipse Cucumber failed to show the warning for undefined step definitions
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SCn40.jpg)

Comment: Next time copy the text from the IDE console and paste it here. Don't use images for these sort of thing.

Comment: Hi and welcome to StackOverflow! Visit the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), take a [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and see [How to Ask a Good Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Please also check out: [Why Shouldn’t I Post Code in an Image Format](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/13991219)

Answer (score 1):

> Eclipse Cucumber failed to show the warning for undefined step definitions

What do you expect to happen? This is normal behavior. The Cucumber library doesn't run in the background to warn you that a test step in a feature file doesn't have the required step definition.  Think about what you are asking. If the plugin did that during development, how often will it warn you? You can also have dozens of steps not fully implemented. Instead, the plugin depends on the developer to do his or her job and not create test steps that are not fully implemented. After all, you should not be pushing feature files that have not been validated with at least one successful run. So... what's the harm in giving you the warning when it is trying to execute the step?